# RocketRaid gives me stuttering computer

Tags: raid, freeze

I have a SANS DIGITAL TowerRAID TR8M-BP (with the RocketRaid 622 raid device) with 5 x SAMSUNG Spinpoint F4 HD204UI 2TB 5400 RPM SATA 3.0Gb/s harddrives in a RAID 5.  It connects via 2-esata cables.  My drivers are up to date.

When I'm writing data to the drives my computer stutters (meaning freezes for a 1/2 second every 2 seconds or so).  My screen freezes, my music goes into a loop, its really annoying.

I get the same thing in windows 7 as I do in Linux.  The only difference is it seems to happen less in Linux, but occassionally Linux will crash (I've never had Linux crash for any other reason, so I'm assuming they have poor Linux drivers and kernal mod).

Any tips for how to deal with this?

Comment: You might post the model number of the enclosure tower and how it is connected to the PC. Have you checked for a firmware or driver update for the product?

Answer (score 2):

What are your cache settings on the RAID card? Is it waiting to write data to the drives, or is it caching writes?  Also, have you checked with your Raid Tool to make sure one of disks does not have errors?

Also, it sounds like some of these come with an adapter card that does not include hardware Raid, or support that many devices..  Some of the comments on NewEgg sound like this:

[I called tech support, got right through, after talking with tech he sold me on a new a new controller RocketRAID 2314 (hardware raid). I purchased 8 1.5TB drives, and have it configured in one RAID 5 with online hot spare.](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=16-111-051&SortField=0&SummaryType=0&Pagesize=10&PurchaseMark=&SelectedRating=-1&VideoOnlyMark=False&VendorMark=&IsFeedbackTab=true&Keywords=(keywords)&Page=1#scrollFullInfo)

Answer (score 1):

Login to the RAID management "website" and disable the caching policies on each drive. This stopped the stuttering issues for me.